# PHP If offer is rejected 3 times, remove div

Tags: php

I have a "offer" button that lets the user enter a price offer. If they enter 3 offers and all are rejected, I want the div to be removed.

```
if(isset($_POST['offer_form']) && !empty($_POST['offer_form'])){
    if($offers === "1"){
            if($_POST['offer_form'] >= $price_offer){
                echo 'Accepted';
            }else{
                    echo '<div class="offer_errors">Offer Rejected</div>';
            }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="offer_errors">Sorry, no offers can be made</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your full code which div you want to remove from where

Comment: Add one column to database and increment with one for every reject Offer and check counter three before display result

Comment: yeah but it will have to be a unique database row for each user viewing that item right..

Comment: how can you reject the offer when you not store offer to database ??, if you use realtime 'offer and reject' you can use `$_SESSION` like @Edd said.

Comment: i have a stored number that the seller will accept, if it doesn't match with the buyers offer than it rejects it. I want to have a counter that counts 3 rejections and then disables the offer button

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Sessions

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['offer']=1;
```

Something like that.

to increment is do something like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['offer']) && $_SESSION['offer'] != ''){
    $offer = $_SESSION['offer'];
    $offer += 1;    
    $_SESSION['offer'] = $offer;
}else{
    $_SESSION['offer'] = 1;
}
```

Just get some ideas from this. I dont think this is ready for what you need. Just modify it suit your needs.

Comment: and how do i increment it?

Comment: Yeah it works but it makes it count for the whole website rather than just on the current item page. Is there a way to tell it to reset the count for each unique id page?

Comment: You can use different session names for each page.. like $_SESSION['page1_offer'] = 1;

Comment: well users will post items on so I have to have it dynamically change, i could use the $_GET['id'] inside i guess

Comment: tried doing $_SESSION[$_GET['id']] but that didn't work

Comment: what is value of $_GET['id']?

Comment: post.php?id=100 every page is different id though

Comment: Can you try to put $_GET['id'] on a variable on a variable first? $pageid = $_GET['id']; $_SESSION[$pageid] = 1;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49709/discussion-between-gadgetster-and-edd-a)